On postgresql, I tried a lot of attempts to rule out admin does not exist problem
This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers. You can edit the question so it's on-topic or see if it can be answered on another Stack Exchange site, but be sure to read the on-topic page for a site before posting there.
Closed 3 hours ago.
This question is about programming for postgresql servers scripts and docker containers scripts as well sql scripts.
I have a postgresql server db admin, user admin, password admin in local. When into the container, the admin is superuser.
When accessing with db params (os.getenv of the right values, that when printed, give the right values as well) into a python scripts with psycopg2, the connection says admin is not a created role.
The problem is bypassed if I use the docker package and connect to docker and get the answer directly from the query type SELECT * FROM.
But it worked yesterday and now the admin problem persists. I should be able to get in with the db parameters.
I checked pg_hba.conf and the permissions are given correctly. Is there a specific of access or other config file that is causing this ? (no error into the dockerfile, docker-compose, init.sql etc.)
By changing the IP address of the local container from localhost to 172.25.0.2, it says that it can't connect (connection time out). And with localhost it has the admin problem.
